# Dual mode ARC/GC and Core Foundation bridging

Tags: objective-c, garbage-collection, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

I am writing code intended to work both under ARC and under Garbage Collection.

Here's a bit of code that uses Core Foundation as it might be written specifically for ARC:

```
CFTypeRef ref=CFCopySomething();
// At this point ref has retain count 1.
id obj=(__bridge_transfer id)ref;
// Ref still has retain count 1 but is now managed by ARC.
[obj doSomething];
// ARC will release ref when done.
```

It seems this is equivalent to:

```
CFTypeRef ref=CFCopySomething();
// At this point ref has retain count 1.
id obj=(__bridge id)ref;
// Now ref has retain count 2 due to assigning to strong variable under ARC.
CFRelease(ref)
// Now ref has retain count 1.
[obj doSomething];
// ARC will release ref when done.
```

The benefit of the latter being that the CFRelease call allows the GC to collect the object. But I'm not sure about calling the CFRelease after transferring to ARC with the bridge-casted assignment.

It certainly seems to work. Is this code OK?

Comment: It's worth mentioning to the readers that `__bridge` casts have no meaning on non-ARC compilation units, i.e., the compiler will simply ignore them when compiling with `--objc-gc`, making your 2nd code snippet compatible with both ARC and GC. (Just saying that cause I had to search.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second code snippet is correct, and indeed is the best way to handle both ARC and GC. You could also use CFMakeCollectable when creating the object, and then have the CFRelease done as follows:

if ([NSGarbageCollector defaultCollector] == NULL) CFRelease(myCFString)

But I like better what you have with just one call that works for both environments.

Answer (score 1):

Nick,

As the CFObjects are not handled by ARC, you may actually want to keep the manually managed code here. ARC is really focused on Cocoa and not Core Foundation. That said, you said the code works but does it leak? Remember ARC code with the wrong compiler flags fails by leaking. In this Apple documentation, they claim that ARC does not manage CF objects: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html.  Hence, I think your __bridge code leaks and await your confirmation or rejection from Instruments' leaks tool.

Andrew

Comment: I can confirm that the code does not leak when compiled under ARC.

Comment: Nick, OK, I'm glad you confirmed that. To your GC question, as your CFRelease can occur anywhere after your last use, why are you putting it before your last use and hoping that ARC/GC sort it out? If you just stick to the standard pattern for CF objects, then you don't have to think about the ARC v GC issues. IOW, in your second block, move the CFRelease to the last point you need the item. Neither ARC nor GC will be much smarter about it than you. (BTW, I think your bridging assignment does nothing but change the name. No allocation semantics are changed.) Andrew

Comment: Under the GC, CFRelease is required to mark a CF object as collectible. It is conventional to do this at the time of creation (often using CF/NSMakeCollectable, but CFRelease works just as well).  Likewise, with ARC I want to hand over the object to ARC as soon as possible. It all does actually work.

Comment: Nick, I'm glad it's working for you. Isn't GC an asynchronous process? Can't items that have no references or have been made collectible be reaped at any time? While the likelihood of an early reap is remote, it can, and on some systems will, happen. Isn't the certainty of manually handling the CF object worth moving the release till after your last use? Andrew

Comment: Re the GC, yep it's asynchronous, but it tracks which objects are actually in use. It's pretty clever! It even works on CF objects, once you have CFReleased them. Shame it was deprecated, really. Though ARC is an awesome alternative.